# How do I initialise my ViewModel in my SwiftUI app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI App which uses a public API to download cocktail data by name but I am not very familiar with SwiftUI and I cannot see a way of initialising my view model in my DetailsView file.

here is my swift file if cocktail data structs;

```
struct Drinks: Decodable {
    var cocktails: [Cocktail]
}

struct Cocktail: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return idDrink
    }
    let idDrink: String
    let strDrink: String
    let strDrinkThumb: String
    let strAlcoholic: String
    let strGlass: String
    let strInstructions: String
    let strIngredient1: String?
    let strIngredient2: String?
    let strIngredient3: String?
    let strIngredient4: String?
    let strIngredient5: String?
    let strIngredient6: String?
    let strIngredient7: String?
    let strIngredient8: String?
    let strIngredient9: String?
    let strIngredient10: String?
    let strIngredient11: String?
    let strIngredient12: String?
}
```

here is my NetworkManager class;

```
class NetworkManager {
        
    func fetchData(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Drinks, Bool) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        var drinks: Drinks?
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                guard let safeData = data else { return }
                do {
                    drinks = try decoder.decode(Drinks.self, from: safeData)
                        completion(drinks!, false)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    if error.localizedDescription == "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing." {
                            completion(drinks ?? Drinks(cocktails: [Cocktail]()), true)
                    } else {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel class;

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var urlString: String
    @Published var drinks: Drinks = Drinks(cocktails: [Cocktail]())
    @Published var dataIsFound: Bool = true
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        FetchData()
    }
    
    func FetchData() {
    
        networkManager.fetchData(urlString) { results, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.drinks = results
            self.dataIsFound = !error
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my DetailsView struct;

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        
        List(viewModel.drinks.cocktails) { cocktail in

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text(cocktail.strDrink + "  -")
                        .navigationTitle("Cocktail by first letter")
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                    Text(cocktail.strAlcoholic)
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                }
                
                WebImage(url: URL(string: cocktail.strDrinkThumb))
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20.0, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20.0, alignment: .center)
                    
                
                Text("~ Ingredients List ~\n").frame(alignment: .center)
                
                ForEach(viewModel.buildIngredients(cocktail), id: \.self) { ingredient in
                    Text(ingredient)
                }
                
                Text("\n~ Recipe Instructions ~\n\n")
                
                Text(cocktail.strInstructions + "\n").fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This way it comes from the parent if you want to initialize them in the detail use StateObject instead

Comment: @loremipsum I have tried ```@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel(urlString: urlString)``` but the project won't build because ```self``` is not available until after property initialisers have run

Comment: Initialize the stateobject with an empty initializer, make urlString a Published variable, add didSet to it and call FetchData in the didSet vs the init, and set urlString in the onAppear

Comment: That is because you are trying to initialize it with `urlString` that you are passing in separately. In your parent, make the call  as `DetailsView(viewModel: ViewModel(urlString: urlString)`. Make your `@ObservedObject` a `@StateObject` and remove `let urlString: String` from `DetailsView()`.

Comment: @loremipsum I've done all that but the urlString initialising value needs to come from outside the DetailsView class. That's why I initialise DetailsView with a urlString parameter

Comment: You didn’t read the whole thing, set the variable onAppear vs on init you can set the default value to nil or empty.

Comment: @loremipsum what do you mean by "vs"?

Comment: @Yrb I have updated my code to show your suggestion.

Comment: Instead of, call FetchData in the didSet instead of the init

Comment: A `@StateObject` is owned by the view it's declared in, you have to initialize it  `@StateObject var viewModel =  ViewModel()`

Comment: The app is not fetching any more data from the API now

Comment: You need to rethink the structure of the view model. From my understanding so far, the view model does not to be concerned with `urlString`, but the network manager does. I don't know from where you're getting your urlString, but maybe instead of initializing the view model with the urlString, maybe a better approach is to store your urlString as a static constant somewhere and initialize the network manager with the urlString. This way you will not need a urlString property inside your view model.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 15):

Here is one common pattern, using `ViewModel()` to initialize and then calling `fetchData` on `onAppear`:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let networkManager = NetworkManager()
    @Published var drinks: Drinks = Drinks(cocktails: [Cocktail]())
    @Published var dataIsFound: Bool = true
    
    
    func fetchData(urlString: String) {
        //call fetchData on network manager
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    
    var urlString : String
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        
        List(viewModel.drinks.cocktails) { cocktail in
            //list content
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchData(urlString: urlString)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to use your `View'`s `init`. In this case, the `@StateObject`'s init is called with the `urlString` passed into the `View`. Because `StateObject`'s `wrappedValue` parameter uses and autoclosure and only gets run if the view is added to the hierarchy, you don't have to worry that the view model will be re-initialized on every `init` of the `View`.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let networkManager = NetworkManager()
    @Published var drinks: Drinks = Drinks(cocktails: [Cocktail]())
    @Published var dataIsFound: Bool = true
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        fetchData(urlString: urlString)
    }
    
    func fetchData(urlString: String) {
        //call fetchData on network manager
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel : ViewModel
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(urlString: urlString))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //body content
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: How would one solve this issue without using StateObjects?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean -- the entire question and answer are centered on using `ObservableObject`s.

Comment: The problem is that StateObject is only available on iOS 14 and especially macOS 10.15. Now when you create the view model outside the view that uses it you need to make sure to destroy it afterwards. On Apps that rely entirely on NSHosting / UIHosting, this works fine. As soon as an app transitions to more SwiftUI initialising on the outside does not really work and without the StateObject the model would reinitialise itself every time the view changes (when created in the init of the view).

Comment: Sounds like something that deserves a separate question.